# why react behaves weird when I move tr tag into a deep level?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a table where it renders the following data to their respective column, but however I want to add an id key into `key`, but at the moment to add the key the data disappear, what am I missing?

```
const arr = [
  {
    demo: [
      {
        _id: "xx122",
        name: "Historian",
        tags: ["demo"],
        things: [],
        list: [],
        queries: [],
        notes: []
      }
    ],
    demo_2: [
      {
        _id: "xx123",
        name: "Demo",
        tags: ["demo_2"],
        things: [],
        list: [],
        queries: [],
        notes: []
      }
    ]
  }
];
const keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);

export default function Demo() {
  return (
      <div>
          <table className="table">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      {keys.map((i) => (
                          <th key={i}>{i}</th>
                      ))}
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {keys.map(key => 
                {arr[0][key].map(item => <tr key={item._id}><td>{item._id}</td></tr>)}
              )}
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  );
}
```

this works, but I need to add `item._id}` to `tr` tag

```
              <tbody>
              {keys.map(key => 
                              <tr>
                {arr[0][key].map(item => <td>{item.technique_id}</td>)}
                </tr>
              )}
              </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why such a complex data structure is being used. but it was kind of fun to work with. Here is how I solved it.

We need keys in both tr and tds as both of them are being rendered dynamically.

```
{keys.map((key) => {
            let row = arr[0][key];
            let items = Object.keys(row[0]);
            return (
              <tr key={row[0]._id}>
                {items.map((item, i) => (
                  <td key={i}>{row[0][item]}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
```

you can reference this example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-goldwasser-hthdz?file=/src/App.js:0-1097

Comment: if I want to access only to `name` in your example, how would I do it? example `var.name `

Comment: If you mean, just displaying name as an item in row then that would be even easier.
              <tr key={row[0]._id}>
                <td>{row[0].name}</td>
              </tr>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use react Fragments because Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM. Refer to [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) for more details.

So another solution to fix this issue is just to add <></>.

```
<tbody>                
{keys.map(key => 
  <>
   {arr[0][key].map(item => <tr key={item._id}><td>{item._id}</td></tr>)}
  </>
)}              
</tbody>
```